# Laravel 8.5's Validation is not working and getting an error

Tags: json, laravel, validation

[image]I am just calling an API with one array parameter with the required validation. But I am getting always an error message. The weird thing is that it has been working since I created the project but it suddenly stopped working today. I also cleared config:cache and apply the composer dumpautoload command till the issue remains the same.[image]

Comment: what headers do you have?  Are you sending Accept Application/json ?

Comment: Yes! I did it and I did solve this issue. Actually, it was the issue of environment variables. One of them is not matched with existed environment variable and that cause this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, try to dump all the input data using `dd` helper and see if the input format is correct
so in the first line of your function dump it like below the check the output

```
dd( $request );
```

secondly, use the [validate](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) function of `$request` object
so instead of calling and using  `Validator` class,
call it on the request object at the very first line of your function

```
$request ->validate([
    'booking_data' => 'required|array'
]);
```

and you don't need to manually check any validation and manually return something, it will automatically throw an error if it fails